# Db2 errors post installing through InfoSphere Federation Server

Tags: db2, db2-luw, ibm-infosphere

I am planning to do SQL replication through InfoSphere Federation Server and installed the latest version from IBM website, while running the executable iisetup.exe, federation tool create the db2 instances and ask for db2user password and port as well, I have given all the required information and at the end installation and JDBC wrapper was successfully completed. after that I have open the db2 command prompt through administration. I am getting issue in running all the command eg

```
C:\db2\BIN>db2start 
SQL1390C The environment variable DB2INSTANCE is not defined or is invalid. 

C:\db2\BIN>db2 GET DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION 
DB21018E A system error occurred. The command line processor could not continue processing.
```

Comment: please edit your question to show the  plain text output of the `db2level` command,  show also your Windows version and edition (winver), and confirm that you run those commands in the window that results from running `db2cwadmin.bat`.

Comment: Also there may be more details in your db2diag.log (diagnostics) file to help you with this configuration issue.

Comment: Interested to know what version of InfoSphere Federation Server you managed to download from IBM. Federation server has been replaced by Db2 for a while now https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/infosphere-federation-server-clarification-regarding-entitlement-and-support-after-september-30-2017#EOS1